# How to check if points are within a sector of a circle

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

I finished a 7 hour coding assessment but missed a question that required too much math for me.  It was a backend position but for some reason this game programming related question was included I am guessing just to gauge how much ability I would have should they want to consider transferring me in the future.
Apologies in advance for pasting images but I could not find anything similar online to link to because I am not a gamer and not familiar with where to find such things.
I can select an x,y pt on the game screen for a special attack.  This point is relative to the player's position at the origin.

[image: game screenshot]

I am given parameters x,y I just mentioned, r which is the radius of the attack, ie. the distance from the origin towards the clicked x,y point in which the attack is valid as well as parameter d which is the angle in degrees to both sides of this the line r in which the attack is valid.  Valid meaning monsters in this pie slice of the circle will get damage from the player's special attack.

Here is another picture:

[image: graph of game]

The last paramter I am given are the (x,y) coordinates of all the monsters on the game screen.

I have to return the number of monsters that take damage, ie. are within the pie-shaped area of the attack range.

I know a tiny bit about polar to cartesian but not sure even where to begin with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the point $(x_1,y_1)$. It forms an angle of $\text{atan2} (y_1,x_1)$ from the origin. This angle plus/minus $d$ gives $\text{atan2} (y,x) ± d$, and since the slope of a line is $\tan \theta$ (think about opp/adj), the straight lines have equation $y = \tan(\text{atan2} (y_1,x_1) ± d)x$.

Thus the region is bounded by:

$$y ≥ \tan(\text{atan2} (y_1,x_1) + d)x$$
$$y ≥ \tan(\text{atan2} (y_1,x_1) - d)x$$
$$x^2+y^2≤r^2$$

Comment: You can use atan2 twice, but we only need tan the second time, since $\theta$ and $\theta + \pi$ give the same line (think about this graphically).

Comment: That's awesome!  I was just  going to start trying something similar, but watered down, after seeing these two sites:  https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming-examples/convert-cartesian-polar-coordinate.htm and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-whether-point-exists-circle-sector-not/

Comment: No problem! The picture you linked is actually quite helpful because you can follow it step-by-step.

Comment: The inequality signs change depending on the angle, but $x^2+y^2 ≤ r^2$ stays the same as that's the equation of a disk (whose perimeter is a circle).